# Type 'Observable<{}[]>' cannot be converted to type 'AngularFireList<any[]>'

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable

I'm pretty much new to Firebase and I was going through this course: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-status-update-app-w-reactions-using-angular-v4-and-firebase but my issue is that this tutorial is out of date so there are some issues I encountered with Firebase

On the tutorial, there is a recent function that was used to get the most recent posts... previously the code looked like this:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Method to get the recent statuses from Firebase
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

recent(amount: number): FirebaseListObservable<any[]> {
  return this.statuses = this.af.list('/statuses').map(arr => arr.reverse()) as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
}
```

I later found out that `FirebaseListObservable` is outdated and now it's `AngularFireList`

So I changed my code to look like this

```
recent(amount: number): AngularFireList<any[]> {
  return this.statuses = this.af.list('/statuses').map(arr => arr.reverse()) as AngularFireList<any[]>;
}
```

I used a similar question from [Property 'map' does not exist on type 'AngularFireList<{}>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190065/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-angularfirelist) and tried changing my code to:

```
recent(amount: number): AngularFireList<any[]> {
  return this.statuses = this.af.list('/statuses').valueChanges().map(arr => arr.reverse()) as AngularFireList<any[]>;
}
```

`Type 'Observable<{}[]>' cannot be converted to type 'AngularFireList<any[]>'.`

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property 'map' does not exist on type 'AngularFireList<{}>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190065/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-angularfirelist)

Comment: Did you `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` ?

Comment: I did and that did not work...
I used that previous post but their solution did not fix my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use `map()` as a pipeable operator with RxJS 5.5+. This would allow you to reverse the array returned from `.list()`. You should then be able to simply type it as an `Observable<YourMagicType[]>`:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

recent(amount: number): Observable<YourMagicType[]> {
  return this.af.list<YourMagicType>('/statuses').valueChanges().pipe(
    map(arr => arr.reverse())
  );
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it out.